# I'm really confused about using 'SAYS' and 'SAID'

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, reported-speech, backshifting

1. Renzo **said** that he'll show up the big event.
2. He **says** that he can cook with casts on his arms.

What's the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Upvoting...

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the difference is one of tense. But I take it that you are asking when each should be used.  In casual speech, if the statements were maid fairly recently and are still true, as far as the speaker knows, either past or present tense could be used..

> Renzo said that he'll show up the big event. He said that he can cook with casts on his arms.

This seems to be an example of back shifting reported speech. Renzo said these things some time in the past, so the speaker uses the past tense.

> Renzo says that he'll show up the big event. He says that he can cook with casts on his arms.

Renzo said these things in the recent past, and the speaker thinks that they are still true, that Renzo has not changed his mind. So the speaker uses the present tense.

Either option is valid and natural, and the basic meaning is the same, although the emphasis is different.  But one should probably stick to one tense or the other if the two statements are made together or close to each other. Otherwise the change of tense could be confusing. If Renzo made the two statements at significantly different times, then using different tense for them might make sense.

Answer (score -1):

"Says" is the third person of the verb "to say" in the simple present tense. So is used with he/she/it and every third-person subject, e.g. "He says that he loves pizza everytime we see a pizzeria".

"Said" is the past simple and the past participle form of the verb "to say". Basically, if you're talking about something happened in the past, you must use it.
"Sad" is used by every singular and plural person. It's always the same.

Comment: In OP's second example, the present tense is used to describe habitual action. This action (saying he can cook) happened in the past, but we expect it to happen again, so we use the present tense.

Comment: This answer is incorrect – **@ThePhoton**'s comment is correct.